Elasticsearch Conditional based querying
I'm working with Elasticsearch and have documents with fields that can be empty (""). Here's an example of the document structure:
    [
          {
            "company_code": "ABC",
            "client_id": "12345",
            "section": "abc",
            "module": "substitute",
            "priority": "1"
          },
          {
            "company_code": "ABC",
            "client_id": "",
            "section": "abc",
            "module": "buy_it_again_products",
            "priority": 1
          }
          {
            "company_code": "",
            "client_id": "",
            "section": "abc",
            "module": "buy_it_again_products",
            "priority": 1
          }
    ]

I need to create an Elasticsearch query that follows these conditions:

When company_code, client_id, and section are given, return documents matching all three fields with non-empty values.
If no documents match the first condition, then only return documents where company_code and section match, but client_id is empty ("").
If no documents match the first and second conditions, then only return documents where only section matches, and both company_code and client_id are empty ("").

The response should include documents satisfying only one condition according to the priority listed above.
I have tried the following query and also msearch.
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "term": { "company_code": "ABC" } },
              { "term": { "client_id": "12345" } },
              { "term": { "section": "abc" } }
            ],
            "boost": 100
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "term": { "company_code": "ABC" } },
              { "term": { "section": "abc" } },
              { "term": { "client_id": "" } }
            ],
            "boost": 20
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "term": { "section": "abc" } },
              { "term": { "company_code": "" } },
              { "term": { "client_id": "" } }
            ],
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    { "_score": "desc" }
  ]
}

The issue with this approach is, this returns all the documents matching all three conditions. Any way can get the expected result through ES?

did you try with putting this 3 condition as separate query in _msearch ? msearch will return response in same order of query you pass in it. So application side you can put logic and check result and take which ever first is available.

@SagarPatel yes, that returns all the results separately. I want to handle this entirely within ES without requiring any additional application side logic.

You can use script query to achieve this by putting your result but that will be performance costly. hence, will suggest to msearch and handle at application level.

In above example, it is single document with array field which have 3 element or 3 different es document.

@SagarPatel it is three different es documents,

How many document you are expecting in result ? is it always one or more then one ? If you are expecting more then one document in result then even script query will also not work as it will execute per document level and not index level. Best option is to go with _msearch only, I don't see any other option for your use case.

Unfortunately, Elasticsearch does not support if-else logic or similar conditional constructs in queries. you can often use logical operators like (and, or, not) to replace simple if-else logic, but in your scenario it wasn't doable, the closest alternative would be using aggregation. where you can pick the group at the end nothing more.
here is a code example:
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "term": { "company_code": "ABC" } },
              { "term": { "client_id": "12345" } },
              { "term": { "section": "abc" } }
            ],
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "term": { "company_code": "ABC" } },
              { "term": { "section": "abc" } },
              { "term": { "client_id": "" } }
            ],
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "term": { "section": "abc" } },
              { "term": { "company_code": "" } },
              { "term": { "client_id": "" } }
            ],
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
   "aggs": {
    "filter_groups": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "first_group": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { "term": { "company_code": "ABC" } },
                { "term": { "client_id": "12345" } },
                { "term": { "section": "abc" } }
              ]
            }
          },
          "second_group": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
               { "term": { "company_code": "ABC" } },
               { "term": { "section": "abc" } },
               { "term": { "client_id": "" } }
              ],
            }
          },
          "third_group": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { "term": { "company_code": "" } },
                { "term": { "section": "abc" } },
                { "term": { "client_id": "" } }
              ],
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_docs": {
          "top_hits": { "size": 10  // Number of documents to retrieve per group
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

in this way, you will get all the results with the query:
company_code, client_id, and section are found +
company_code, client_id = "", and section are found +
company_code = "", client_id = "", and section are found +
meaning that the three cases will be retrieved, then after that you will do filter aggregation to split them into three groups, then when you execute you can pick the desired group.
I guess this is the maximum Elasticsearch can do.

Great Solution, but here also he needs to filter result at application level and select group which having data. Aggregation are also performance costly hence I will still suggest to go with msearch and pick result which have data in order.

yes msearch is the best solution
